# Cursor lag in Wine 1.6 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wine, games, cursor

I recently installed Wine 1.6 on my Dell D650 laptop with the intention of running Empire Earth Gold (the first edition). It starts up fine and can open the start up menu, but the cursor lags, disappears while moving, and leaves a trail of glitches over the screen until the page is refreshed. And the whole thing freezes when I hit "start" after configuring the game. The only way to get out is to log out or reboot the system. I haven't been able to find any applicable patches for this release of wine. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Well, I tried all of your suggestions, and they did help. I'm actually running Wine 1.8 now, and I put everything in the game itself on the lowest settings (graphics, music quality, etc.) And its playable now, but only barely. There is still an unbearable lag when using the touchpad or keyboard mouse. And a regular mouse is completely out of the question. I'll keep searching and post any updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this may not necessarily solve your problem, you often have a better chance of getting something to run with Wine by using the latest version of Wine. You can install Wine 1.7 by following the [instructions on this page](https://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu) – or in short run the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.7
```

If that still doesn’t help, then you should look at [Wine’s AppDB](https://appdb.winehq.org/) for the specific application you’d like to run. For the Gold Edition of Empire Earth there is also [an entry](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25242); it suggests to run `winetricks directmusic` in a terminal to get rid of the freeze (run `sudo apt-get install winetricks` before, if you don’t have it, yet). The mouse issue will probably stay, though (which is also noted in the AppDB entry).

Answer (score 0):

If it is Wine's bug, you could try to install Wine-staging. It is an extention, which provides a lot bug fixes and more. You'll find more information on their websites.